# A bag contains 16 white balls and 14 black balls. The balls are drawn with replacement.

Tags: probability

What is the expected number of white balls drawn before the $\mathrm{13}^{\mathrm{th}}$ black ball is drawn?

So here is the total of 30 balls and we take 13 balls so $\binom {30}{13}$

and 13 balls should be white ball so $\binom {16}{13}$

Can anyone help? ...thank you

Comment: Note: "The balls are drawn *with* replacement".

Comment: Negative binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

The balls are drawn *with* replacement, so the probability that the ball in any particular draw is white will be a constant $16/30$.

The expected count for white balls drawn before the thirteenth black ball will be $$\sum_{w=0}^\infty \frac{w\binom{w+12}{w}16^w14^{13}}{30^{w+13}}\phantom{=\dfrac{16\cdot 13}{14}}$$

However, if you recongnise the family of the distribution, you can look up the well known closed form.

Answer (score 0):

I get the probability of the $n^{\text{th}}$ ball being the $13^{\text{th}}$ black ball to be
$$P_n^{(13)}=\left(\frac{14}{30}\right)^{12}\left(\frac{16}{30}\right)^{n-13}{{n-1}\choose{12}}\left(\frac{14}{30}\right)$$
Just the binomial probability that $12$ of out the first $n-1$ balls drawn are black times the probability that ball $n$ is then black. To find the mean value of $n$, we sum $n$ times $P_n^{(13)}$ over all possible values to get
$$\begin{align}\mu&=\sum_{n=13}^{\infty}P_n^{(13)}=\sum_{n=13}^{\infty}\left(\frac{14}{30}\right)^{13}\left(\frac{16}{30}\right)^{n-13}{{n-1}\choose{12}}n\\
&=\sum_{n=13}^{\infty}\left(\frac{14}{30}\right)^{13}\left(\frac{16}{30}\right)^{n-13}\frac{n(n-1)!}{12!(n-13)!}\\
&=\sum_{n=13}^{\infty}\left(\frac{14}{30}\right)^{13}\left(\frac{16}{30}\right)^{n-13}\frac{13n!}{13!(n-13)!}\\
&=13\sum_{m=14}^{\infty}\left(\frac{14}{30}\right)^{14-1}\left(\frac{16}{30}\right)^{m-14}\frac{(m-1)!}{13!(m-1-13)!}\\
&=13\left(\frac{30}{14}\right)\sum_{m=14}^{\infty}\left(\frac{14}{30}\right)^{14}\left(\frac{16}{30}\right)^{m-14}{m-1\choose13}\\
&=13\left(\frac{30}{14}\right)\sum_{m=14}^{\infty}P_m^{(14)}=13\left(\frac{30}{14}\right)\end{align}$$
In the above we transformed the sum via $n=m-1$ and then used the fact that the sum of the probabilities of all possible outcomes is $1$, this time for the $n^{\text{th}}$ ball being the $14^{\text{th}}$ black ball.

Answer (score 0):

The expected number of white balls drawn before the $13$th black ball is the expected number before the twelfth black ball plus the expected number between the twelfth and the last. Continuing this it is clear that the expected number is $13$ times the expected number of white balls before the first black ball.

Now the expected number of balls chosen including the first black ball is well-known from coupon collection and other problems and is the sum of a simple geometric progression - it is $\frac {30}{14}$. But note that this includes a black ball, so the answer you want is ...